# mono installation stalls - mcs is not producing progress

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, mono-framework

I am trying to build [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/) from its [git repository](https://github.com/mono/mono) on [Freescale P2020RDB board](http://www.nxp.com/products/microcontrollers-and-processors/power-architecture-processors/qoriq-platforms/p-series/p2020-reference-design-board:P2020RDB). I've managed to build it on host machine with `Debian 8` with cross compiler and it works like a charm. However, due to customer's demands, I was forced to create custom `Linux` distro with preinstalled toolchain for selected CPU. Now I am trying to follow [Compiling mono from git](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/compiling-mono/compiling-from-git/), however, the installation process stalls at:

```
if test -w /run/media/sda1/mono/mcs; then :; else chmod -R +w /run/media/sda1/mono/mcs; fi
cd /run/media/sda1/mono/mcs && make  NO_DIR_CHECK=1 PROFILES='binary_reference_assemblies net_4_x xbuild_12 xbuild_14         ' CC='gcc' all-profiles
*** Assuming PLATFORM is 'linux'.
make[3]: Entering directory `/run/media/sda1/mono/mcs'
make profile-do--binary_reference_assemblies--all profile-do--net_4_x--all profile-do--xbuild_12--all profile-do--xbuild_14--all
make[4]: Entering directory `/run/media/sda1/mono/mcs'
make PROFILE=basic all
make[5]: Entering directory `/run/media/sda1/mono/mcs'
Mono JIT compiler version 4.8.0 (Stable 4.8.0.371/902b4a9 Tue Feb  7 00:58:05 CET 2017)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
        TLS:           __thread
        SIGSEGV:       normal
        Notifications: epoll
        Architecture:  ppc
        Disabled:      none
        Misc:          softdebug
        GC:            sgen
make[6]: Entering directory `/run/media/sda1/mono/mcs'
make  -C .//packages
make[7]: Entering directory `/run/media/sda1/mono/mcs/packages'
make all-local
make[8]: Entering directory `/run/media/sda1/mono/mcs/packages'
make[8]: Nothing to be done for `all-local'.
make[8]: Leaving directory `/run/media/sda1/mono/mcs/packages'
make[7]: Leaving directory `/run/media/sda1/mono/mcs/packages'
mcs /warn:0 /noconfig /r:System.dll /r:mscorlib.dll /out:build/deps/basic-profile-check.exe build/common/basic-profile-check.cs
```

I've also checked if the `/run/media/sda1/` runs out of sapce, but this is not the problem:

```
root@p2020rdb:/run/media/sda1/mono# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       6.7G  480M  5.9G   8% /
devtmpfs        344M  8.0K  344M   1% /dev
tmpfs           376M  160K  376M   1% /run
tmpfs           376M   44K  376M   1% /var/volatile
/dev/mmcblk0p1  504M  8.5M  470M   2% /run/media/mmcblk0p1
/dev/sda1       111G  1.6G  103G   2% /run/media/sda1
/dev/sdb1       3.8G   17M  3.8G   1% /run/media/sdb1
```

What could be wrong here?

**ADDENDUM 1:** When I was building custom `Linux` distro for the `P2020RDB` board, I've already preinstalled other version of [meta-mono](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-mono) using [Yocto](https://www.yoctoproject.org/):

```
testuser@debianvirtual:~/QorIQ-SDK-V1.9-20151210-yocto/build_barebone$ bitbake fsl-image-minimal
Loading cache: 100% |########################################################################################################################################| ETA:  00:00:00
Loaded 2524 entries from dependency cache.
Parsing recipes: 100% |######################################################################################################################################| Time: 00:00:01
Parsing of 1966 .bb files complete (1964 cached, 2 parsed). 2525 targets, 184 skipped, 0 masked, 0 errors.
NOTE: Resolving any missing task queue dependencies

Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION        = "1.26.0"
BUILD_SYS         = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING   = "Debian-8.7"
TARGET_SYS        = "powerpc-fsl-linux-gnuspe"
MACHINE           = "p2020rdb"
DISTRO            = "fsl-qoriq"
DISTRO_VERSION    = "1.9"
TUNE_FEATURES     = "m32 spe ppce500v2"
TARGET_FPU        = "ppc-efd"
meta
meta-yocto
meta-yocto-bsp    = "(detachedfromb74ea96):ddf114933ccfc6e3ce51a10e8e8f95e514b73578"
meta-oe
meta-networking
meta-perl
meta-python
meta-ruby
toolchain-layer   = "(nobranch):214e1801d0efc38d3b6142bdc0d8e58ca593e34c"
meta-freescale    = "(detachedfrom7fb32a2):7fb32a20983a0ebd5503eb42e851550b0deb8679"
meta-freescale-internal = "(detachedfrom220bff8):220bff8b2030e5af7393b5870d74c6f0af0d76d1"
meta-freescale-extra = "(nobranch):ced26c806cb566b1400a2f4f26a94d8d44d13233"
meta-linaro-toolchain = "(nobranch):3f1933242062d1cf473d20b86fa4582963ff9441"
meta-mono         = "master:c122ccfb820ac8fdc72e94bf9fa696b566e55b75"

NOTE: Preparing RunQueue
NOTE: Executing SetScene Tasks
NOTE: Executing RunQueue Tasks
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 3214 tasks of which 3214 didn't need to be rerun and all succeeded.

Summary: There were 2 WARNING messages shown.
```

However, because some nasty problems in preinstalled mono, we had to clone the repository, change some source files and now we are trying to reinstall it.

Comment: Which answer exactly, is considered exemplary?

Comment: @Burgi I've clicked not on purpose wrong "reason" for bounty, but I need help regarding issue.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark... did you correctly set `./configure`?

Comment: @Hastur, according to [compile from git document](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/compiling-mono/compiling-from-git/), I do not run `./configure`, but `./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr/local && make && make install`.

Comment: Why do you accord to _compile from git_ if you are compiling the tarball? Check for exit codes each time even because you are using `&&` instead of the blind `;`. Maybe with a warning it can exit with an error code and stops. If you are compiling from Git, did you read [One Stop Shop Build Script (Debian)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/compiling-mono/linux/)?

Comment: @Hastur yes I did, no success, I've ugpraded whole question.